# convergence of total variation measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $X = [0,1]$. Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of regular Borel measures on $X$, which converges to a measure $\mu$ on $X$ in weak-star, i.e. for any $f\in C_0(X)$, we have $\int_X f \mu_n(dx) \to \int_X f \mu(dx)$.

Is it possible to show that $|\mu_n|$ converges to $|\mu|$ in weak-star, or any other modes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Comment: could you be more specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|\mu_n|$ may  not converge to $|\mu|$ in the weak-* sense. The following is a counter-example.

For every $n\ge 1$, let 
$$\mu_n:=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\delta_{\frac{k}{n}}-\delta_{\frac{2k-1}{2n}}\right),$$
where $\delta_x$ denotes the [Dirac measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) centered at $x$. Then for every $n\ge 1$, 
$$|\mu_n|=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\delta_{\frac{k}{n}}+\delta_{\frac{2k-1}{2n}}\right),$$

so in the weak-* sense, $\mu_n$ converges to $0$ but $|\mu_n|$ converges to the Lebesgue measure.

---

**Edit:** A similar but simpler counter-example is as follows. Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two sequences in $[0,1]$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n=a$ for some $a\in[0,1]$ and  $a_n\ne b_n$, $\forall n$ . For every $n\ge 1$, let 
$$\mu_n:=\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta_{a_n}-\delta_{b_n}\right)\Longrightarrow |\mu_n|=\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta_{a_n}+\delta_{b_n}\right).$$
Then in the weak-* sense, $\mu_n$ converges to $0$ but $|\mu_n|$ converges to $\delta_a$.